# In a dependently typed programming language is Type-in-Type practical for programming?

Tags: dependent-type, type-theory

In a language with dependent types you can have Type-in-Type which simplifies the language and gives it a lot of power. This makes the language logically inconsistent but this might not be a problem if you are interested in programming only and not theorem proving.

In the [Cayenne](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/291251.289451) paper (a dependently typed language for programming) it is mentioned about Type-in-Type that "the unstratified type system would make it impossible during type checking to determine if an expression corresponds to a type or a real value and it would be impossible to remove the types at runtime" (section 2.4).

I have two questions about this:

- In some dependently typed languages (like Agda) you can explicitly say which variables should be erased. In that case does Type-in-Type still cause problems?
- We could extend the hierarchy one extra step with `Kind` where `Type : Kind` and `Kind : Kind`. This is still inconsistent but it seems that now you can know if a term is a type or a value. Is this correct?

Comment: Let me know if this question is okay here or more suited for the cs or cstheory stackexchanges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> the unstratified type system would make it impossible during type
> checking to determine if an expression corresponds to a type or a real
> value and it would be impossible to remove the types at runtime

This is not correct. Type-in-type prevents erasure of *proofs*, but it does not prevent erasure of types, assuming that we have parametric polymorphism with no typecase operation. Recent GHC Haskell is an example for a system which supports type-in-type, type erasure and type-level computation at the same time, but which does not support proof erasure. In dependently typed settings, we *always* know if a term is a type or not; we just check whether its type is `Type`.

Type erasure is just erasure of all things with type `Type`.

Proof erasure is more complicated. Let's assume that we have a `Prop` universe like in Coq, which is intended to be a universe of computationally irrelevant types. Here, we can use some `p : Bool = Int` proof to coerce `Bool`-s to `Int`. If the language is consistent, there is no closed proof of `Bool = Int` so closed program execution never encounters such coercion. Thus, closed program execution is safe even if we erase all coercions.

If the language is inconsistent, and the *only* way of proving contradiction is by an infinite loop, there is a diverging closed proof of `Bool = Int`. Now, closed program execution can actually hit a proof of falsehood; but we can still have type safety, by requiring that coercion must evaluate the proof argument. Then, the program loops whenever we coerce by falsehood, so execution never reaches the unsound parts of the program.

Probably the key point here is that `A = B : Prop` supports coercion, which eliminates into computationally relevant universe, but a parametric `Type` universe has no elimination principle at all and cannot influence computation.

Erasure can be generalized in several ways. For example, we may have *any* inductive data type with a single constructor (and no stored data which is not available from elsewhere, e.g. type indices), and try to erase every matching on that constructor. This is again sound if the language is total, and not otherwise. If we don't have a `Prop` universe, we can still do erasure like this. IIRC Idris does this a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I just want to add a note that I believe is related to the question. [Formality](https://github.com/maiavictor/formality), a minimal proof language based on self-types, is non-terminating. I was involved in a Reddit discussion about whether Formality can segfault. One way that could happen is if you could prove `Nat == String`, then cast `42 :: Nat` to `42 :: String` and then print it as if it was a string, for example. But that's **not** the case. While you can prove `String == Int` in Formality:

```
nat_is_string: Nat == String
  nat_is_string
```

And you can use it to cast a `Nat` to a `String`:

```
nat_str: String
  42 :: rewrite x in x with nat_is_string
```

Any attempt to **print** `nat_str`, your program will not segfault, it will just hang. That's because you can't erase the equality evidence in Formality. To understand why, let's see the definition of `Equal.rewrite` (which is used to cast `42` to `String`):

```
Equal.rewrite<A: Type, a: A, b: A>(e: Equal(A,a,b))<P: A -> Type>(x: P(a)): P(b)
  case e {
    refl: x
  } : P(e.b)
```

Once we erase the types, the normal form of `rewrite` becomes `λe. λx. e(x)`. The `e` there is the equality evidence. In the example above, the normal form of `nat_str` is **not** `42`, but `nat_is_string(42)`. Since `nat_is_string` is an equality proof, then it has two options: either it will halt and become identity, in which case it will just return `42`, or it will hang forever. In this case, it doesn't halt, so `nat_is_string(42)` will never return `42`. As such, it can't be printed, and any attempt to use it will cause your entire program to hang, but not segfault.

So, in short, the insight is that self types allow us to encode the `Equal`, `rewrite` / `subst`, and erase all the type information, but not the equality evidence itself.